# To Find The Maximum sum of sub array

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

Given an array arr of N integers. Find the contiguous sub-array with maximum sum.

Input:
N = 5
arr[] = {1,2,3,-2,5}
Output:
9
Explanation:
Max subarray sum is 9
of elements (1, 2, 3, -2, 5) which
is a contiguous subarray.

Comment: Lots of algorithms described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). Attempt to implement one of them & update your question with the issues that you face. Also read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Please also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this code:

```
from sys import maxint
def maxSubArraySum(a,size):
  
max_so_far = -maxint - 1
max_ending_here = 0
  
for i in range(0, size):
    max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
    if (max_so_far < max_ending_here):
        max_so_far = max_ending_here

    if max_ending_here < 0:
        max_ending_here = 0  
return max_so_far
```

For better understanding, check this explanation: [Kadane's Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/)